What value of K is used when when a player is removed from FIDE rating list due to dropping below 1400?
My FIDE rating recently went under 1400, hence I lost my rating. I have K=20 at the moment. So my question is what will be the K from now on? 20 or 40?

You will start again from being an unrated player, so will get a K of 40 once you regain a rating.

7.2.1      Players whose ratings drop below 1400 are shown as unrated on the next list. Thereafter they are treated in the same manner as
any other unrated player


7.1.4      A rating for a player new to the list shall be published when it is based on at least 5 games against rated opponents. This
need not be met in one tournament. Results from other tournaments
played within consecutive rating periods of not more than 26 months
are pooled to obtain the initial rating. The rating must be at least
1400

To regain an rating, you must get an initial rating of over 1400 calculated from all rated games over the preceding 26 months being a minimal of 5 rated games that include at least one win. See section 8.2 of https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B022024 for calculations.
